# Image from network with Glide too small on Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am trying to download an image from the network and display in the ImageView with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) using scaleType="centerInside" option.

For some reason, the image, when downloaded from the network, looks much smaller on the screen than when the same image is put into the ImageView from resources.

Example:

[image: Portrait view with two different images]

Both images can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Ccu.jpg). I would argue that even those images that have been set from resources look smaller than they could actually be when compared to what I see on my laptop. I understand that there is something related to the screen density in play, but how can I make these images be of "user-friendly size", e.g., a bit larger?

Even a [different image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNg3r.jpg) of 600x250 px size is ridiculously small on the phone (with ImageView's layout_height and layout_width set to "wrap_content").

[image: Image in landscape mode]

Code from the Activity:

```
public class DisplayImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.display_image_activity);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        setTitle("Hello StackOverflow!");

        ImageView top_left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.top_left);
        ImageView top_right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.top_right);
        ImageView bottom_left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_left);
        ImageView bottom_right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_right);

        String[] urls = new String[] {
            "http://imgur.com/6jMOdg0.png",
            "http://imgur.com/AhIziYr.png"
        };

        top_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_left);
        top_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_right);
        Glide.with(this)
             .load(urls[0])
             .signature(new StringSignature(new Date().toString()))
             .into(bottom_left);
        Glide.with(this)
             .load(urls[1])
             .signature(new StringSignature(new Date().toString()))
             .into(bottom_right);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

display_image_activity.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/_toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        style="@style/match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            style="@style/match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                style="@style/wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_resources"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="From Resources"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/top_left"
                android:background="@color/Linen"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_resources"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/top_right"
                android:background="@color/Linen"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/top_left"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/top_left"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_resources"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_network"
                android:layout_below="@id/top_left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="From Network"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_left"
                android:background="@color/Linen"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_network"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_right"
                android:background="@color/Linen"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bottom_left"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bottom_left"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_network"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have any solution? I have same problem here.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem. Glide tries to interpret what my app needs and transforms the images accordingly, resulting in too small images in some places. In my case the ImageViews use `adjustViewBounds="true"` and MaxWdth/Height leading to problems

While I am not anything close to being a Glide Expert, I found a quick fix working for me.

I simply added a `.dontTransform()` mehod call, which in my case is OK since I use thumbnails that already have been pre-scaled.

```
GlideApp.with(context).load(fireStorage).dontTransform().into(imgView);
```

(Using a Placeholder would probably also have helped, but again, for me this was the easiest way)

Answer (score 0):

Your images cannot be bigger than what you defined:

```
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
```

Try

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't change anything, and it shouldn't. The size that I defined is how large I want the ImageViews to be (different background around images is for ImageViews). The images inside should be larger, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImageView`s can be that fixed size if you want although they should be flexible with `match_parent`/`wrap_content`.

I don't know what Glide does for sure but it looks like the resolution of the images from the network is smaller than the ones from resources. The `android:scaleType="centerInside"` gives you the behaviour that the image will be SHRUNK until both dimensions of the image fit in the `ImageView` and it's aspect ratio is maintained. If you want the images to expand to fit the `ImageView` you probably want `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` instead. You might also want `android:adjustViewBounds` to be true/false depending on how you want it to behave if you decide to make the dimensions flexible.

The documentation for scaleType is useful here: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#CENTER

Comment: Images from resources and network are exactly the same.
I do not want to use "fitCenter" because that would not really work for small images (they would be stretched to the full size of the ImageView). I still want to use "centerInside" but the problem is that no matter the size of the image, when put in ImageView it is displayed too small. I find it hard to believe that in the second screen (landscape) a 600px wide image should be displayed so small.

Comment: On a phone that has a QHD screen the resolution is 2560x1440. In landscape that means that a 600x250 image is less than 1/4th of the width of the screen and less than 1/5th of the screen's height. So wrapping the content allows the ImageView to match the size of the image. If you consider the high resolution of the screen that image seems a perfectly reasonable size (at least to me)

Comment: hmm. Your explanation sounds correct. Still, if the resolution of the phones keeps getting larger, the same images will keep getting smaller and smaller on the screen. Doesn't sound right. Maybe it is possible to somehow "multiply" the size of the given image based on screen density? Not sure, how that would work.

Comment: That's what the unit of measure on Android phones "dp" is for. It means "density independent pixels" https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview this is a useful link for dp. Despite you using the dp to scale your image view correctly your making the image scale based on its pixels which it doesn't sound like you want to do. You could specify the different coloured background with a LinearLayout and have a centralised ImageView inside it which is the right size and then use fitCenter

Answer (score 0):

This code saved my time. It works for me!

```
        //Get actual width and height of image
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)url.getContent());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Timber.e("Image Loading Error %s", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (bitmap != null) {
            final float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
            final int dpWidthInPx = (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * scale + 0.5f);
            final int dpHeightInPx = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * scale + 0.5f);

            //Set result width and height to image
            GlideApp.with(imgAns.getContext())
                    .load(imgUrl)
                    .override(dpWidthInPx, dpHeightInPx)
                    .into(imgAns);
        }
```